# Google App engine Go Runtime still serving the old code

Tags: google-app-engine

I first deployed  Go runtime Guest book application a week ago on App-engine . I replaced it with Hello-world Go app . The deployment was successfull with the log as seen in the screenshot below 
[image: Screenshot of successfull deployment] . But the new code deployed hasnt yet been updated . When i visit the url (myapp-xxx.appspot.com) it still serves the old template page instead of just printing hello world . The new Routes are also not working . I uploaded the version 2 of the app and versions page of the app engine on developers console  still shows the old version which i had first uploaded a week ago . Its hampering my development time , How long does it take to just update my changes in the code ??

Comment: As soon as the deploy script finishes - your app should be updated with the latest changes and ready for viewing.  Go to the admin console under versions to see the versions that are uploaded.  If uploading a new version number, you can prepend that value to the url.  [VERSION].[APPID].appspot.com

Comment: My mistake ! I was checking a different app ..Yes , it has been updated !! thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just to put it as an answer, here is what [Jeff Deskins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4316235/jeff-deskins) said :

As soon as the deploy script finishes - your app should be updated with the latest changes and ready for viewing. Go to the admin console under versions to see the versions that are uploaded. If uploading a new version number, you can prepend that value to the url. [VERSION].[APPID].appspot.com